# Get the solution of a math function at point x

Tags: r

I would like to get the solution of function for specific x's
e.g.

```
f <- expression {x^2}
```

now I'm looking for the y for e.g

```
xn <- 2
```

so what are my option to get the 4 I expect?

Comment: unclear what you're asking, but *maybe* `eval(f,list(x=xn)` ?

Comment: Are you tied to using `expression` instead of `function`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this is what you are looking for:

```
f <- function(x) {
  x^2
}
f(2)
4
f(-2)
4
```

Answer (score 1):

The structure of a function is given by:

```
MyFunction <- function_name(arg1, arg2, ... )      ##any number of arguments that you want
{ 
      statements              ##the expression you want to write
      return(object)          ##the result of your expression
}
```

It's look like you want to obtain the square of x number.

Then:

```
f <- function(x){
x^2
return(x)
}
```